# Xamarin - how i can i make my button display different text each time it is clicked?

Tags: xamarin

I have a button added using `<Button Text="Next" Clicked="Button_Clicked"></Button>` How can I make my button display different text each time it is clicked?

Comment: Copy/Paste the code behind of your page

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a name to your `Button` in order to get hold of it in your `Button_Clicked` method.

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton" Text="Next" Clicked="Button_Clicked" />
```

Then in your code behind:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    MyButton.Text = "Hello, World!";
}
```

Comment: No I want the button to display different texts. Like when it is clicked first it will say apples, then when clicked again it will say oranges, then when clicked again it will say bananas and so on.

Comment: What prevents you from doing that?

Comment: I dont know how to do that. That is why I asked.

Comment: Sorry, I won't help you with that. I've shown you how to change the Text of the button. Now it is your turn to summon your brain cells and think a bit.

Comment: That was my question anyway so your answer is useless

Comment: Well I am trying to help you, but if what I throw at you doesn't stick and you don't show any signs of understanding what is suggested. Then it seems effortless to continue. Good luck with solving _your_ problem.